# Account for pedigree effects in linear mixed model

Tags: random-variable, mixed-model

I'm a student in biomedical engineering. I wanna analyze difference of brain size between controls and patient.

But it is very hard to me because there are some siblings in data.

I would like to see the group difference accounting for sibling effects.

```
    Group Age Br_size Subj_ID Family_ID
    1     14    100      1      1
    1     17    113      2      2
    1     19    124      3      3
    1     16    102      4      1
    1     12    119      5      4
    1     19    124      6      5
    .     .     .        .      .      
    .     .     .        .      .      
    2     19     99      45     28
    2     13    118      46     2
    2     13    120      47     29
    2     19    112      45     30
    2     13     98      46     31
    2     13    100      47     3
```

For 47 subjects, 15 subjects have no relationship to others but the others have least one sibling in this data.

How do I make a formula? I think..

```
    fitlme(tbl, 'Br_size ~ 1+ Age + Group + (1 + Subj_ID  |Family_ID );
```

Is it right?
I am looking forward to your response and comments.

Comment: Welcome to the website. I assume that this is not a MATLAB *syntax* question but rather a *notation* question. Wilkinson notation [[Wilkinson and Rogers, 1976](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2346786)] is widely used in MATLAB, R and GENSTAT (its original platform). So in that sense I assume you ask about the symbolic description of a factorial model. If you have a MATLAB specific question [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) will be place to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the MathWorks link on [Wilkinson Notation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/wilkinson-notation.html) is your best bet to understand what  Wilkinson notation coding entails. Somewhat ironically, it is probably better more comprehensive than any single R resource I have come across so far ([Pinheiro & Bates, 2002](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387989579) is probably more comprehensive as a whole but there we talk about a 500+ page book then...).

Having said the above, I believe you are over-complicating yourself with that formula. The obvious thing is to try a crossed random effects structure akin to:
`Br_size ~ 1+ Age + Group + (1|Subj_ID) +  (1|Family_ID)` in which case you recognise you have some subject-specific variation as well as some family-specific variation. Your previous mode where you used `(1 + Subj_ID | Family_ID )` encode a random slope across subjects which is irrelevant when you for a nominal variable as `Subj_ID`.

Comment: In many previous studies, It has been reported about relationship between siblings. Some studies used mixed model to i-th member of j-th family. If I try to this, can I change the Subj_ID to membership of family?

Comment: Yes, it seems reasonable as you present it. Check what `Family_ID/Subj_ID` does. The slash (`/`) is used to define a nesting structure and maybe this is more natural to your case.